# Bounding the radius of minimum enclosing disk of a finite set

Tags: discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite set of ($n$) points in $\mathbb R^2$ of diameter $1$, i.e. any two points in $X$ have distance at most $1$. We need to prove that $X$ can be included in a disk of radius at most $1/\sqrt 3$.

I proceeded with the inductive proof - I can prove the base case of $n = 3$: by considering an equilateral triangle of side $1$.

Next, I assume the statement true for all $3 \le i \le n$, and I am trying to prove for $n+1$.

Consider set $X_n$ of $n$ points for which it is true by inductive hypothesis. "Insert" the $n+1$st point and call the resulting set $X_{n+1}$
There are 2 cases:

1. Convex hull of $X_{n+1}$ is defined by $\le n$ points. Then by convexity we can consider only the points on the boundary, and the statement it true using inductive hypothesis.
2. Convex hull of $X_{n+1}$ is defined by $n+1$ points. Here, I am not sure how to use the inductive hypothesis.

Any hints or lemmas that I need to prove for proving the second case?

Comment: Instead of induction, you can try to show on the boundary of the minimal containing disk (in terms of its radius), there are two possibilities:
there is either a pair of points in $X$ forming a diameter of the disk.
or there are 3 points in $X$ on the boundary forming an acute triangle. In the second case, compare the radius of disk with the longest side of the triangle.

Comment: @achillehui How to prove that those are the only possibilities?

Comment: It didn't mean there are either 2 or 3 points on the boundary. It is possible there are more than 4 points there. It means among the points on the boundary, you can find either a pair of points forming a diameter or three point that forms an acute triangle. If you are given a configuration that you cannot find either of these, you can shrink the disk while still containing all the $n$ points, this will violate the assumption that you are working with the minimal containing disk.

Comment: I understand that. What I am asking is - how to prove that the disk won't contain, say, $4$ points on its boundary?

Comment: It can contain 4 points. but out of the 4 points, either a pair of them is a diameter or three of them form an acute triangle. If all 4 points fall on the interior of a semi-circle, then out of the family of circles passing through those two out of four points who are farest apart, you will find a circle has a smaller radius and yet contains all the $n$ points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known exercise on Helly's theorem.

Suppose that $n\ge3$, and let the points be $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$. The following statements are equivalent:

$\quad$ (1) There exists some point $C$ such that $P_k\in\overline{B}(C,\tfrac1{\sqrt3})$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

$\quad$ (2) There exists some point $C$ such that $\overline{P_k C}\le \tfrac1{\sqrt3}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

$\quad$ (3a) There exists some point $C$ such that $C\in \overline{B}(P_k,\tfrac1{\sqrt3})$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

$\quad$ (3b) $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n \overline{B}(P_k,\tfrac1{\sqrt3})\ne\emptyset$.

The disks $\overline{B}(P_k,\tfrac1{\sqrt3})\ne\emptyset$ are convex, so for proving (3), by Helly's theorem, so it is sufficient if every three of them have a common point.

Comment: What does $\overline B(C, \frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$ denote?

Comment: Closed disk with center $C$ and radius $1/\sqrt3$.

Comment: So for proving the given statement, I've to prove 1. The equivalence of statements and 2. How (3) is true by Helly's theorem. Right?

Comment: (1), (2) and (3) are equivalent, so Helly $\Rightarrow(3)\Rightarrow(1)\Rightarrow$ your statement.

Comment: I don't see the equivalence right away, so I guess I'd have to prove it.

Comment: OK, I have split (3) into two parts to make it more obvious...

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!